# Subtotal (Excl. Tax) shown with tax

Tags: checkout, tax, shopping-cart, ce-1.9.1.1

I have magento core issue, I think

In the shopping cart Subtotal (Excl. Tax) is displayed including tax.
I did not notice this problem occurring before I installed Devsters_Gift_Cards
That I have uninstalled now, replaced with old database and files too, I think...
I have tried
deleting caches
reindexing
compiling
switching off compiler
changing tax settings
But still I get Subtotal (Excl. Tax) with tax included.

The weirdest thing
After I visit the checkout and go back to cart it is corrected and tax sum is added before grand total

What is going on there? I am in trouble. Any hints?

I am using magento 1.9.1.1
The page is here
http://oasis-solutions.ee/c/new-ray/index.php/

And an image

[image: Same sums show up]

Comment: `That I have uninstalled now, replaced with old database and files too, I think...` double check that. Beside this, xdebug on and dig into the code what happens. This is no core feature/bug I heard of. Updating might solve your issue too, but if you want to understand what happens: xdebug.

Comment: Oki, thanks, trying.
Just remembered another weird thing -  I can not switch off gift options anymore. Before I could turn them off from settings->sales, wonder if those twp issues can be connected

Comment: I figured it out, going to post it as an answer
Under Default Tax Destination Calculation
Default Country was set to USA, that was clearly wrong, and it messed up somehow the correct display of the taxes, how supid of me  :P
The gift optionproblem still  remains as a separate issue

Comment: And for  disabling gift messages
System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable modules output  Mage_GiftMessage worked for my onestep checkout, huh, what a relief!

Comment: Are you sure about your template?

Comment: Jeah, my template was just fine, it was the language configuration causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what was causing weird behaviour:
Under settings
Default Tax Destination Calculation -> Default Country
was set to USA,
that was the wrong country for my store,
and it messed up the correct display of the taxes in the cart.

Hope it helps some newb like me, get Your countries right :)